# PHP can't run exec()

Tags: php, pdftk

The basic setup I am trying to accomplish is using pdftk with PHP on IIS

I am trying to setup pdftk to run with PHP for processing on our internal server. I have tested that pdftk does work through command on the server but I cannot get it to run through php. I have tried changing from `exec()` to `passthru()`, `system()`, and `shell_exec()` just to be sure it wasn't specific.

The main solution I'm finding is saying that the IUSR account needs at least read & execute privileges on `cmd.exe` in the `system32` folder. I have tried this and it did not change anything. I always get either "Unable to fork" or "Unable to execute" depending on which command I'm using.

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages? Also, make sure those functions haven't been disabled in your `php.ini` file...

Comment: It sounds like `exec()` may be running perfectly well, but the problem lies thereafter in `cmd.exe` / `pdftk`. Can you verify `exec()` runs fine from PHP's perspective?

Comment: See what you get when you do `exec("whoami");`

Comment: exec() won't run from PHP that is the main problem. I can confirm the command does work form cmd.exe on the server. Regardless of what command I give with exec() I get the error "Unable to fork". I will be checking in a minute to make sure it is not disabled in php.ini.

Comment: I just checked php.ini and it looks like nothing is set for disable_functions. The line is simply:

disable_functions =

Comment: Checked again for other issues. Safe mode is not enabled. I also tried enabling read & execute access to the system32 folder itself and it made no difference. This is normally something we would obviously not do but since it is a test machine we decided to try it.

Comment: Hi, the safe_mode of PHP is Off ?

Comment: Yes, safe mode is set to Off

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It was caused by conflicting IIS settings in these 2 locations:

- Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity
- Web site > Authentication > Anonymous Authentication

The app pool was set to a domain user. This was correct for how we needed to run our web site.

The web site authentication was set to the same "Specific user" as the application pool. It should have been set to "Application Pool Identity". After I changed it to "Application Pool Identity", `exec()` ran successfully.